# Which library is used for setting validations in Codemirror Json Editor?

Tags: validation, codemirror

Which library is used for setting validations in Codemirror Json Editor ?

Answer (score 1):

See on this page: https://codemirror.net/demo/lint.html

which uses amongst other serveral source also this: https://codemirror.net/addon/lint/json-lint.js

and when using the source-view you will find this:

```
// Depends on jsonlint.js from https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint
```

so this would be the answer: https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint

**A JSON parser and validator with a CLI.**

http://zaach.github.com/jsonlint/